# How to overwrite specific top level partition in multi-level partitioning in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql, partition

My table have 4 partition in this order:period_dt,year,month,date

I period_dt is static partition (value is an argument) and year,month,date are dynamic.So I know period_dt partition value which I want to overwrite.

```
newInputDF.write().mode("overwrite").partitionBy("period_dt","year","month","date").parquet("trg_file_path");
```

Using above command Spark overwrites all partition.But in my case for example if partition exists overwrite it otherwise append it.I want to overwrite partition at period_dt level.

One method would be to provide complete path:

```
inputDFTwo.write().mode("overwrite").parquet("trg_tbl/period_dt=2016-09-21/year=2016/month=09/date=21");
```

But year,month,date are dynamic

```
second to use hive query with HiveContext.
```

Is there any other way to overwrite specific partition?

**Solutions I came up with:**

```
hiveContext.sql("INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_name PARTITION(period_dt='2016-06-08', year,month,date) , select x,y,z,year,month,date from DFTmpTable");

and

DeleteHDFSfile(/table/period_dt='2016-06-08')
DF.write().mode("append").partitionBy("period_dt","year","month","date").parquet("path")
```

Comment: in this case how you have done with hive query ? can you add code snippet of hive query?

Comment: Hi @RamPrasadG I added solutions above.But I am wondering is there any performance difference in using any of the above.I ended up posting one more query...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810659/insert-overwrite-vs-delete-hdfs-partition-and-write-parquet-file-in-spark